# How to display the image so that it fits the entire screen?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_x="0dip" 
    android:layout_y="0dip"
    android:background="@drawable/mlview1" />
```

I'm using android emulator 2.2 . My image occupies the screen horizontally but vertically shows a large gap from the Bottom. The image size is 800X600 . should it be re-sized and then used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that:
1. Both height and width on both parent and child is **fill_parent** 
2. You are setting the **src** property and not the **background** one on the image

Note: You also don't need the **layout_x** nor **layout_y**